# ArgumentError: Missing required argument: clientId

Tags: bootstrap-5, amadeus

while running bootstrap-flight-search-form-part-2 using command
npm run start
it gives error like
[image]

Comment: Hi Ankita, you need configure the API_KEY & API_SECRET as the article explain: https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/bootstrap-flight-search-form-part-2 ; Did you register in the Portal? https://developers.amadeus.com/register

Comment: I follow process like article but it's not working also create file process.env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run the project locally do the following steps:

- Clone the [repository](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/Building-a-Flight-Search-Form-with-Bootstrap-and-the-Amadeus-API-Part-2)
- Install the dependencies with

```
npm install
```

- Add your API key and API secret at [app.js](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/Building-a-Flight-Search-Form-with-Bootstrap-and-the-Amadeus-API-Part-2/blob/2d9cd084dcebffba4d718c9a4aa1deaedf31b1b2/app.js#L6)

```
const amadeus = new Amadeus({
  clientId: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  clientSecret: 'YOUR_API_SECRET'
});
```

- Start the server with

```
npm run start
```